# How to set Listener on Button from another layout?

Tags: java, android

I have button (`@+id/signOutButton`) in `fragment_user` layout. I want to setOnClickListener on that button in my `LoginActivity`. This is how my activity look like:

```
public class LoginActivity extends BaseActivity implements
        View.OnClickListener {

   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        // Button listeners
        findViewById(R.id.signInButton).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.signOutButton).setOnClickListener(this); <<< this line already is crashing my app
        findViewById(R.id.disconnectButton).setOnClickListener(this);
```

In this code `setOnClickListener` is crashing my app.

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
```

How to repair that ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First inflate other xml file :

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_user, null);
```

then get a reference to the Button from the inflated view and set OnClickListener:

```
Button signout = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.signOutButton);
 signout.setOnClickListener( 
 //your code
 );
```

Comment: This did not work for me. The app keeps crashing regardless of if I inflate the layout :(

Comment: Nevermind, I forgot to put the "view." before the "findViewById". This thing still isn't working, the clicklistener is completely unresponsive for the button in the other layout, but at least it's not crashing anymore.